# Having a decorative element between links but still contained within a list?

Tags: html-lists, hyperlink

So I was thinking of putting a decorative element between links such as // for example. 
So it would be LINK1 // LINK2 // LINK3 // LINK4 // LINK5 but ONLY between the links for decoration purposes such as

[EXAMPLE of coding](http://jsfiddle.net/SsY2Q/)

Is there a way to do the same with a html list or in a more cleaner or technically correct format? Or would this be the way to code something like that since I keep reading that lists are a better way of formatting a links menu. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Just a thought, if you're using an HTML list you'd have decoration in front of your first link - // LINK1 //LINK2... you get the idea.
You could always generate the links dynamically and decorate them with a language like php, JavaScript, etc. though ;)

Comment: So how would I do it with a scripting language? I actually thought of a way with the list with css though and with the :before and :after code do you think that would work?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method is how you do it (that's the way I do it also :)
But yes, using an HTML list is the more technically correct method. Especially for non-CSS devices, the links will be a decent-looking bullet list, rather than a long string of links (which may not look good without CSS).

Comment: Ah gotcha, I actually thought of a way with the list with css though and with the :before and :after code do you think that would work?

Comment: the css pseudo element I think it's called that. Where you will do div:before and then those results would be applied to the beginning of the element or something.

Comment: I just read about it on [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_before.asp); that's a pretty nifty CSS feature! . . . As far as your question; as long at it looks right on the browsers, you'll be okay :D

Comment: I wish I knew of a way to do it with a list since that would be more friendly without the css.